# Bootstrapping Alibaba Cloud Message Service in Android Application?

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I want to use the Alibaba Cloud message service within my Android Application. But I see there no Android SDK available. I am trying to use JAVA SDK as an Alternative, there is no luck.

Is this the correct way of using the service or do I have to use the API interface as the final resort?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, In this case, you can use JAVA SDK. JAVA SDK's are compatible with Android, Keep in mind that you might need to resolve the dependencies as mentioned.

- Download the `aliyun-sdk-mns-1.1.8.jar` & `jaxb-api-2.2.12.jar` and place it under app > libs
- And update the gradle with the following lines

`packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        }
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
        implementation files('libs/aliyun-sdk-mns-1.1.8.jar')
        implementation files('libs/jaxb-api-2.2.12.jar')
    }`

The above should fix all the issues.